# How To: validate input string is an ip or a domain PHP

Tags: regex, string, dns, ip, hostname

Just share a tool and debug. Maybe usefull for someone.

**TOOL:**

```
public function ValidateIpOrHostname($inputString)
{
    $ValidIpAddressRegex = "/^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/";
    $ValidHostnameRegex = "/^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/";
    $isValidIp = preg_match($ValidIpAddressRegex , $inputString);
    $isValidHost = preg_match($ValidHostnameRegex , $inputString);

    return ($isValidIp|| $isValidHost)?1:0;
}
```

**TEST:**

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('123.12.12.12') => Result: 1

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('123.123.123.123') => Result: 1

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('1111.1111.1111.1111') => Result: 0

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('234.234.12345.12345') => Result: 0

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('-1.1.1.1') => Result: 0

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('1.1.1.1:80') => Result: 0

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('google.com') => Result: 1

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('www.google.com') => Result: 1

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('http://google.com') => Result: 0

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('http://www.google.com') => Result: 0

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('https://google.com') => Result: 0

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('https://www.google.com') => Result: 0

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('https://google.com') => Result: 0

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('https://google.com:80') => Result: 0

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname(''asdjb aosjkdn') => Result: 0

EXECUTED  : 
ValidateIpOrHostname('asdjb..ewqe.asd..c') => Result: 0

Improves are welcome. 
:)

Comment: And the question is???

Comment: Improves maybe ?? i dont know if this kind of post is accepted. Its my first one.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help and https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Your IP validation doesn't support IPv6, etc. have you considered use of `filter_var` and options `FILTER_VALIDATE_IP`, `FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN`, `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`

Comment: In the future please use RFC2606 and RFC5737 for documentation. Also your code is wrong for many other cases: IDNs, limit if 63 characters per label and 255 in total for names at least and also you do not handle IPv6 which nowadays should be the default. If you search here you will find thousands of answers already with regex to parse these kind of things.

Comment: Also look at resources under https://uasg.tech/information/developers/